# What is the correct way to initialize a NSWindowController object in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa

Try as I might, I can't get the syntax right here. What am I doing wrong?

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    let myThing: Thing

    override convenience init ( window: NSWindow! ) {
        myThing = Thing()
        self.init( windowNibName: "nibText" )
    }

    ...
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `myThing = Thing()` can be placed where the property is declared
2. You should call `super.init`
3. You'll also need to implement `init?(coder: NSCoder)`, Xcode will happily insert a template for this
4. Most likely you'll need another initializer that will load the nib:

Something like this:

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    // the type of myThing will be inferred by the compiler
    let myThing = Thing()

    init() {
        super.init(window: nil)
        // load the contents of the nib, and set the owner as self, which connects the oultlets
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("nibText", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
    }

    // you might no longer need this intializer
    override init(window: NSWindow!) {
        super.init( window: window )
    }

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @cristik, but I'm getting an error on the init line: Overriding declaration requires an override keyword (I don't have an init elsewhere in MainWindowController) and an error on the super.init line: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass NSWindowController. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks again, @cristik. Now I'm getting this error required initializer init(coder:) must be provided by subclass of NSWindowController. Swift 2.1 Xcode 7, OSX project.

Comment: I wrote about this at #3

Comment: Thanks @cristik--Xcode inserted the template, then insisted on my adding required and a super.init call, but I can't figure out the secret recipe for calling the super init... required init?(coder: NSCoder) { // ??? } I feel like I'm falling down a rabbit hole :)

Comment: You should be fine with the content that Xcode created. Did you delete some of it? It should not give errors it it was added by Xcode...

Comment: Thanks @cristik--I finally figured out the secret recipe for calling the super init... required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init( coder: coder ) }

Comment: Swift 4 now has the NSBundle call;          Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: "YourWindowNibName"), owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)